# To find a field with $p^{2}$ elements, where $p$ is prime

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Show that there exists a finite field with $p^{2}$ elements for every prime $p\in\mathbb{N}$.

What I thought is that if I find some irreducible polynomial of degree two over $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, then I will be done. But I had find it for some particular prime $2,3,5.$ But how to find irreducible polynomial of degree two in general in $\mathbb{Z_p[x]}$?

Comment: Show that if $p>2$ there exists a quadratic non-residue $a$ modulo $p$. Then show that $x^2-a$ is irreducible.

Comment: As it turns out all fields with $p^2$ elements are isomorphic, so use whatever irreducible polynomial is convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p=2$. Note that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over the two-element field, for it has no roots in that field.

Now let $p$ be odd. Let $\mathbb F_p$ be the $p$-element field. We have $(-a)^2=a^2$, and if $a\ne 0$ then $-a\ne a$. Thus  there are at most $\frac{p-1}{2}$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb F_p$ that are squares of elements of $\mathbb F_p$. (Actually, there are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$, but we don't need that.)

So there are at least $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements of $\mathbb F_p$ that are not the square of any element of $\mathbb F_p$. Let $b$ be a non-square in $\mathbb F_p$. Then $x^2-b$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_p$.

Answer (score 4):

How many polynomials are there of degree 2?
How many reducible polynomials are there of degree 2?
Let the leading coefficient in both cases be 1.

Comment: there will be $p^2$ polynomail of degree 2,and out of them reducibe will be $p(\frac{p+1}{2})$. so there will be $p(\frac{p-1}{2})$. polynomial wich are irreducilbe.which is ofcourse greater than equal1.hence we are done.is it wright ?

Comment: @Eklavya: That is right. The same argument shows that any finite field has irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ (just replace $p$ by the number of elements of the field). And a similar argument works to show that there are irreducible polynomials of any degree $d>0$, though the counting becomes more and more delicate as $d$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible to find fields of order $p^2$ for a fixed $p$ by what you have done  but to prove it for an arbitrary field you need to use a concept popularly known as **Splitting field**.

Once you get that(I don't know whether you are accustomed to it or not) you need to consider the splitting field of the polynomial

$x^{p^2}-x $  over $\Bbb Z_p$ and you are done.